# looping through a file and creating objects. How do I refer back to them?

Tags: c#, file, object, csv

(minor error in variable assignment code, but that's not that important right now)
I have a CSV file, that I open via Excel. That file contains multiple services (jobs). Each job has a company code associated with it. It's a fairly large file (could go up to 5000 lines or so).

sub-contractor (crew) has a few fields, like their code, and their email address.
service (job) has fields like job number, service date, service description, etc.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:
1) Loop through each line on the spreadsheet
2) On each iteration, I need to create a "job" object and a "sub-contractor" object (if one doesn't yet exist for this company)
3) I then need to add "jobs" to "sub-contractor" objects that are associated with them.

In the end I need to be able to access these sub-contractors and associated with them services that I will use to generate email saying, "hey these are the jobs and this is what's needed from you for them".
Here's the main code I have so far:

```
InitializeComponent();
string file = "myfile.csv";
fileAddress.Text = file;
var excel = new Excel.Application();
excel.Visible = false;
excel.Workbooks.Open(file);

Excel._Worksheet sheet = excel.ActiveSheet;

Dictionary<string, Crew> crews = new Dictionary<string, Crew>();
Crew crew;
string code;
string email;
string account;
string store;
string description;
string status;
DateTime serviceDate;
var sheetLength = sheet.UsedRange.Row;

for (int i = 0; i < sheetLength; i++)
{
    // empty cell means we are done with looping through the column
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sheet.Range["B" + i + 1].Value))
    {
        break;
    }

    code = sheet.Range["I"].Value + i + 1;
    email = sheet.Range["BD"].Value + i + 1;
    account = sheet.Range["C"].Value + i + 1;
    store = sheet.Range["D"].Value + i + 1;
    description = sheet.Range["F"].Value + i + 1;
    status = sheet.Range["N"].Value + i + 1;
    serviceDate = sheet.Range["G"].Value + i + 1;

    if (crews.ContainsKey(code))
    {
        ???
    }
    else
    {
        crew = new Crew(code, email);
        crews.Add(code, crew);
    }
}
```

Here's where I'm stuck: if (crews.ContainsKey(code))
If this crew is already in the collection, I need to add current service to his list.
Here's what Crew class looks like:

```
class Crew
{
    public Crew(string code, string email)
    {
        this.code = code;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public string code { get; private set; }
    public string email { get; private set; }
    List<Job> jobs;

    public void addService(Job job)
    {
        this.jobs.Add(job);
    }
}
```

and this is what the spreadsheet I'm working with looks like:
[image]
If there's a better (faster) way of organizing this data, please let me know. I imagine looping line by line will slow things down significantly.

Comment: What do you mean by 'add current service to his list'? The jobs list?

Comment: List of services for that sub-contractor. So if I had a reference var AA111 to the first crew object I create, I would check if he is in collection and use AA111.addService(job) to his job list (where job is basically a current line in CSV file). The problem is that I don't keep direct reference (if you can call it that) to these objects, so calling crew.addService(job) is not going to work.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you're missing. For instance, why would something like jeremys answer below not work? It looks like you just need to find the existing crew in the dictionary, using the key that you have, and add a job object which you already have the logic for.

Comment: His solution did work. For whatever reason his answer didn't display when I was typing the above, weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the definition of the Job class, so I can't tell you how to instantiate that but once you have it you just do this:

```
if (crews.ContainsKey(code))
{
    // create job object
    crew = crews[code];
    crew.addService(job);

}
else
{
    crew = new Crew(code, email);
    crews.Add(code, crew);
}
```

Note that when you create a crew for the first time, it may mean there is a job already, in that case do this

```
if (!crews.ContainsKey(code))
{
    crew = new Crew(code, email);
    crews.Add(code, crew);
}
// create job object
crew = crews[code];
crew.addService(job);
```

note the bang (!) in the conditional, if the crew doesn't exist create it, but either way once we are sure the crew exists, we add the job.